# Unit test ISR for bare-metal embedded

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, embedded, bare-metal

While there are different unit test system taht can run on the target hardware, I have a very different question.

I want to unit test the synchronization of data between the ISR and the main (and only) thread, possibly on the PC side.

The concept is quite simple: as the ISR cannot be interrupted, I build a small main than uses/produce the data the ISR want in a loop, and for each loop the main will be interrupted in the next line (or better, for each atomic instruction), and the result/consistency of the result verified.

Brute forcing all possible combination should take very little time and give a decent test coverage, without the need to run on the hardware and miss some "almost never but when it happen it goes boom" situation.

So far I had a couple of ideas:

1. in the build binary, for each line of the "main", add a jump to a trampoline function that will decide if is time to run the ISR
2. somehow interface with a emulator like qemu (that should also make sure that if an ASM instruction is not intrinsically atomic could be split up)

Is there anything out there? If not, is there something intrinsically wrong with his approach?

Comment: Are you testing the period of the ISR or its functionality?  On most systems, an ISR is a regular function that can be called by any other function.  If not, you can change the ISR so that it calls a processing function.  Test the processing function from `main` or your unit test function.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No, on the vast majority of systems an ISR is an ISR, which cannot be easily called by software! The normal calling convention is that CPU hardware stacks registers upon calling the ISR. If you call it from software, this part is missing out and you would have to do it yourself manually, with inline assembler. Otherwise, since a normal ISA has separate instructions for returning from an interrupt than from a function, there will be a stack corruption upon returning from the ISR, when the ISR attempts to restore things from the stack that weren't placed there by hardware.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews are you describing my idea #1? because " Test the processing function from main or your unit test function" to me means nothing, is the "magic" that happen there the important point of the question.

Comment: If you are asking how to re-invent the wheel by building a code coverage tool, that's much too broad a question for this site. If you are asking for tool recommendations, then that's explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @Lundin:  In my experience with embedded systems, an ISR is a function.  You place the address of the function into an interrupt register in a processor (interrupt controller or CPU).  When the interrupt occurs, the processor disables interrupts, then jumps to the address in the register.  Although with some processors, the ISR needs to disable interrupts.  A difference between "normal" functions and ISRs is that ISRs may need to execute a "return from interrupt" instruction, or enable interrupts before returning.  If the ISR is called from another function, interrupts will be enabled.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I just explained why it isn't a normal function - different calling convention. Return from interrupt is a specific instruction for a reason.

Comment: If the interrupt cannot be called from another function, then the interrupt should call another function *which can be called from other functions*.  This enables better Unit Testing (or code coverage).

Comment: @Lundin AFAIK there is NO code coverage tool that can do what i just asked for, so there is not "reinvent the wheel". I may be wrong, would be glad to be illuminated. 
You also affirm that what happen in the call of the ISR is quite particular, basically confirming that solution #2 where I have control over the emulator of the chip is the best option. Maybe there is some other way I dont see..

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ISR cannot be.. interrupted unless "Nested interrupt" are enabled. In that case higher priority ISR can interrupt them; but for now lets concentrate on the simple case.
Also the use of a trampoline function does not really solve the issue, how the CPU behave can be different, probably core-dependent